# Visual Studio for Mac - Configuration doesn't target device. Your configuration doesn't target a valid iOS device

Tags: iphone, app-store, visual-studio-mac

Error Message:

> Configuration doesn't target device.
> Your configuration doesn't target a valid iOS device

I want to publish an iPhone app to App Store. So, I tried to perform Archive for Publish an iPhone App by selecting at the top main menu bar:

Build > Archive for Publishing

I have already select a device from the drop down menu at the main top menu bar. But I still receive above error message. What should I do?

I don't have a physical real iPhone. All I use is the iPhone Simulator. Is it a must to use a real iPhone to sign the App and submit to App Store?

### Update

A physical iOS (iPhone) device is no more needed to archive and submit app to AppStore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last option in the list of build devices is a Generic Device, under the heading Build Only Devices.  This option works fine for those without a physical iPhone.

Answer (score 5):

<del>You need to plug in a real physical iPhone into the Mac Laptop.
and target it as target deploy device. Then, this problem will solve.</del>

**Update:** A physical iOS (iPhone) device is no more needed to archive and submit app to AppStore.

For build device, select "Any iOS Device (arm64, armv7)" or Generic Device

Comment: what if I don't have an iOS device?

Comment: @PoorneshV Then, you will see what I see in the first place as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @PoorneshV You may go to ebay and buy a 2nd hand (used) iOS device. which will be lot more cheaper than buying a brand new iOS device.

Comment: You can use a cloud service like MacInCloud, in which case you must select iPhone when you archive, and not iPhoneSimulator (which caused the error message for me)

Comment: @PoorneshV Update: A physical iOS (iPhone) device is no more needed to archive and submit app to AppStore.

Comment: @Savage Update: A physical iOS (iPhone) device is no more needed to archive and submit app to AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is still an issue, but I ran into that issue today: the problemn was that in the fourth column it didnt say "remote device". Click on in so it reads: Release, iPhone, APPNAM.ios, Remote device.

Than your good.